# Is this feasible with plain SQL? Or is a procedure required?

Tags: sql, db2

(This is in DB2 version 9.5)

Say I have a table with four columns:

```
C1: [EmployeeId]
C2: [StartDate] yyyy-mm-dd format
C3: [EndDate]   yyyy-mm-dd format
C4: [Age]
```

The combination [EmployeeId + StartDate] forms the primary key.
Now consider the following sample rows:

```
1     2010-01-16     2010-04-16     29
2     2010-02-16     2010-03-16     33
3     2010-05-16     2010-05-16     31
```

**There is a guarantee that all DAYS will be the 16th day, across all dates, across all rows. No other way about it.**

I'm trying to write a query which will do the following:

For any row where the starting month is less than the ending month (like row 1), replicate the row for each month in between, including the last row. So after running the query, the new rows for row 1 will be:

```
1     2010-01-16     2010-04-16     29
1     2010-02-16     2010-04-16     29
1     2010-03-16     2010-04-16     29
1     2010-04-16     2010-04-16     29
```

For rows where the starting month and the ending month are the same, do nothing. For rows where the the ending month is the month right after the starting month, one new row will be inserted (see the last row above to understand why).

Questions:

1. Is this possible in plain SQL? Or is procedures required?
2. If yes, then how? (hints, code, anything)

Thanks for reading guys. The problem statement is complex, I hope I did a fair job to explain it. Any ambiguity or inconsistency: please point out and I'll edit it asap.

Comment: The biggest concern I see has nothing to do with the SQL but with the guarantee that the days will be the 16th day.Experience tells me this will this will change as soon as enough time has gone by to where you do not understand why you coded it that way to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, 
       date(extract(year from startdate)||'-'||mm.month_nr||'-'||extract(day from startdate)) as stardate,
       first_value(e.enddate) over (partition by employee_id order by e.enddate) as enddate
FROM (
  VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)
) mm (month_nr)
JOIN emp_test e
     ON mm.month_nr = extract(month from e.startdate)
ORDER BY e.employee_id, 
         e.startdate, 
         e.enddate
```

This of course assumes that the datatype for startdate and enddate is `DATE`.
 
And this will only work if all dates are within one single year.

I only tested this with DB2 9.7 but I think it should work with 9.5 just as well.

I think there is a solution for the year-cross problem:

```
WITH yrs (year_month) AS
(
  SELECT DATE(year_nr||'-'||month_nr||'-16')
  FROM (
   VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)
  ) mon (month_nr)
  CROSS JOIN (
    VALUES (2007), (2008), (2009), (2010), (2011), (2012), (2013)
  ) yr (year_nr)
) 
SELECT e.employee_id, 
       yrs.year_month as startdate,
       first_value(e.enddate) over (partition by employee_id order by e.enddate) as enddate
FROM emp_test e
  JOIN yrs ON yrs.year_month between e.startdate and e.enddate
```

As you can see the years are "hardcoded" into the CTE (common table expression). The easiest solution would be to generate a "month/year" table holding all possible values - basically the data that is generated by the CTE.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but yes, the possibility (and likelyhood) that the dates can span across years is a major problem. Will try this and try to build on it. Thanks for the insight, much appreciated.

Comment: The basic pattern to make this work cross-year is to include the possible years somehow in the query. My DB2 is a bit rusty, and I don't know how to generate that dynamically (it's easy for "fixed" values like the month number)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW a set of attribute- and tuple constraints would simplify to some degree:

```
CHECK (EXTRACT(DAY FROM StartDate) = 16),
CHECK (EXTRACT(DAY FROM EndDate) = 16),
CHECK (StartDate < EndDate)
```